# SQL Table Relationship

Tags: mysql, sql

I have created 4 tables that I need to relate to each other and then build a form to add/show data.

I have build the 4 tables in SQL but I'm not sure I have the correct relationships or fields enter so the data can be accessed correctly

```
User Table
  User_ID (Pkey)
  Full_Name (varchar)
  User_Name (varchar)

Department Table
  Dept_ID (Pkey)
  Department_Name (varchar)
  User_ID (int) 

Application Table
  App_ID (Pkey)
  Application_Name (varchar)
  User_ID (int)

Access_Date Table
  Date_ID (Pkey)
  Access_Date (date)
  Removal_Date (date)
  User_ID (int)
```

I want to see a user who has access to one or more applications and what date they got access and what date the access was removed.

A user can have several applications and could be in more than one department.

I think i have the wrong `ID (int)` field related in either the `Access_Date` or `Application` table, but not sure.

I have now added junction tables for `UserDepartment, UserApplications, UserAccessDates`  when I open the form in MS Access 2016, I get a blank page. The form was created using the User table as the main and the department and application and access date as sub-forms.

I believe my relationships may be wrong somehow.

Comment: see [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Did you try joins?

Comment: Why would `User_ID` be in `Department` and `Application` table?

Comment: LESS YELLING IN THE TITLE PLEASE.

Comment: Sorry, won't make titles all Caps in the future.

Answer (score 2):

No, you do not have the right tables.  Let me give you an example with users and departments.  You want three tables for these:

```
Users Table
  User_ID (Pkey)
  Full_Name (varchar)
  User_Name (varchar)

Departments Table
  Department_ID (Pkey)
  Department_Name (varchar)

UserDepartments
  User_ID (int) 
  Department_ID (int)
  Other information, such as Effective_Date and End_Date
```

The first two tables represent two different entities, `Users` and `Departments`.  The third is an association/junction table that implements a many-to-many relationship.

Similarly, you want a `UserApplications` table.  And your access table should show the application.

Notes on naming:

- I generally name tables in the plural, because they contain multiple instances of an entity.
- The primary key is the singular of the table name followed by `_id` or `Id`.
- Primary keys and foreign keys have the same name, to the extent possible.

Comment: Following your advice, I have created the UserDepartments table, the UserApplications table. I believe you comment also said to create a UserAccessDate table (not sure on that). By creating these tables, I should now be able to pull up records for a user to see whatever departments they have or do belong to and whatever applications they have associated with them?

Comment: That sounds like a more complete data model.

Comment: do I need to reference any foreign keys the way I have now created the UserDepartment, UserApplication, and UserAccessDate tables?

Answer (score 0):

From what you have provided, you will be able do determine that user has access to an application but not which application he has access. To provide that information you will need to add the App_Id in the Access_Date table. The Departments are not associated with anything but the user. If departments have anything to do with Applications or Access_Date specific you will need to link the department to the Application and or Access_date tables.

I have added a picture showing the relationships between the tables up to the point that I understand (using ms access).[Relationships](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WAwtS.png)

Here is the new picture.[New Relationships](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHWge.png)

Comment: I missed that you had User_Id in the Department table. It should not be there. You should have the Department_Id in the User table. But that would allow only one department per user. If you have many users in many departments you will need another table with User_Id and Department_Id to show this relationship.

Comment: based on additional information i have been searching through, i created another table (Connection) that has the User_ID, Dept_ID, Date_ID, and App_ID added to it with making each of these ID's a foreign key reference back to the original table. Since everything except Department is a many-to-many relationship would this be correct?

Comment: Your Connection table seems overly complicated. What do the records in the Access_Date table apply to? Is there one record for one application that applies to all users? Is there one record for each user that applies to all applications? Is there one record for one user and one application? Do the Departments have any role in which applications are used by a user?

Comment: A user can be assigned to different departments during an employment period.
A user can be assigned to many applications and have various 'access_dates' 'removal_dates' for those applications.
A department can have many users and many applications associated with a department.

Example, I am in the HR department today and have access to three applications effective Mar 1, 2019.
Next week, I am being transferred to the Customer Service department and all the applications I have access to now will be terminated. I will then obtain access to 5 new applications.

Comment: Final Example.
The boss wants a report of what applications are associated with what departments.

Hope this information helps clarify what I am trying to accomplish. Thank you.

Comment: I will post a new picture to the above answer.